# Store multiple values in a session variable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Before I ask my question, please consider this scenario: a user on my website has a `profileID`. There are some `pluginID`'s associated with this `profileID`.

E.g.: `User1` might have 2, 3 and 5 plugins associated with his profile.

When the user logs in, I store the `profileID` of the user in a session variable `cod`. ON a certain page, the user tries to edit the `plugins` associated with his profile. So, on that page, I have to retrieve those `pluginID`'s from the DB.

I have applied this code but this fetches only the maximum `pluginID` from the DB and not all the `pluginID`'s.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select plugin_id from profiles_plugins where id=(select id from profiles_plugins where profile_id=" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod"]) + ")", con);
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr1.HasRows)
{
  while (dr1.Read())
  {
    Session["edp1"] = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[0]);
  }
}
dr1.Close();
cmd1.Dispose();
```

I was trying to figure out how can I store multiple `pluginID`'s in this session variable?

Thanks

Comment: Aside: you should have a `using` around each of the command, reader, and connection.

Comment: And you should **parametrize** your query! As a general rule, **never** concatenate together your SQL queries - this opens the door to SQL injection attacks - just don't do it.

Comment: And you shouldn't mix data access and session handling in the same piece of code either. A lot of weird things going on here... Also this might be a duplicate of the "question" [multiple rows of a single table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638578/multiple-rows-of-a-single-table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the value to a list or array first and then store the list or array:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select plugin_id from profiles_plugins where id=(select id from profiles_plugins where profile_id=" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod"]) + ")", con))
{

    SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    var yourList = new List<int>();
    if (dr1.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
           yourList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr1[0]));
        }
    }
    Session["edp1"] = yourList;
    dr1.Close();
}
```

Also, read Marc Gravell's comment on your question.

Comment: Ok, I was able to store the values in the session using the List but how do I have to retrieve these values from the session now?

Comment: `var yourList = (List<int>Session["edp1"]);` should work. But I would really refactor your code so you don't do the data access and session handling in the same place.

Comment: Typo in last comment... should be: `var yourList = (List<int>)Session["edp1"];`

Answer (score 3):

You can store whatever objects you like under a session key, not only scalar values. So simply define a custom type containing all the values you would like to store, create an instance of this type and put it into the session.

Comment: If you're going to store custom types in session they should be marked as Serializable if you're going to use ASP.NET State Server or SQL State Server