# how to use sesstion in login windows form c#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, session

i am making Quiz Application on [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).
Question and Answer Load into Form as Form Load.
i have one "NEXT" button in Form, when one question complete ,use push Next Button and go to 
next Question.
Now i want to save session of that user on the basis of he/she Login.
When user Login,`session` start , unfortunatly if `Form Closed` and user again Login then the `session` will start ,where `session` closed(means old situation) not new...
Note:"i m using Windows `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` "..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: So is it that you're looking to save progress?  That way when the user starts the application again it will have the previously answered questions?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it your quiz application writes the users answers to a database when they click on the Next button. Presumably the answers would be recorded in a table with a column for reference to the user ID and a column with the question ID and another the users answer.

If you're using this sort of table structure then couldn't you just see what the last question the user answered was and display the next question to the user when they logged back in?

```
SELECT * FROM AnswersTable WHERE UserID = 'JoeBloggs' ORDER BY QuestionID DESC
```

The top row returned from the above query would tell you the last question they answered (if the QuestionID's were in the same order as the questions.

If not then you could record the date/time of each answer to the table in an AnswerDate column and use this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AnswersTable WHERE UserID = 'JoeBloggs' ORDER BY AnswerDate DESC
```

The above query would return the most recently answered question for JoeBloggs user.

**Edit**: Below is untested code to store and recover session variables. Code assumes you have a database table named UserSessions with the columns InsertionDate, UserID and SessionVar.

Method for getting previous session variable from an sql table named UserSessions. It could be called when the user logs in.

```
    private string GetPreviousSession(string userID)
    {
        string prevSessionVar = "";
        string connectionString = "your connection string to the db goes here";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 SessionVar FROM UserSessions WHERE UserID = @UID ORDER BY InsertionDate DESC", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UID", userID));

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    prevSessionVar = reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
        return prevSessionVar;
    }
```

Method to store the current session var. Could be called on the Form.Closing event.

```
    private void StoreSessionVar(string sessionVar, string userID)
    {
        string iDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        string connectionString = "your connection string to the db goes here";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserSessions (InsertionDate, SessionVar, UserID) VALUES (@IDate, @SessionVarToStore, @UID)", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UID", userID));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SessionVarToStore", sessionVar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IDate", iDate));

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what's not worked? What tables have you got and what data is written to each table when the next button is clicked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638551/store-multiple-values-in-a-session-variable ... check this ,, and convert this logic into my quiz app

Comment: OK, so you want to store the contents of a session variable into a database table when the user closes the form? In that case just write to a database table (maybe you could call it UserSessions) with the date/time, userID, and session variable string, during the Form.Closing event handler. You can then just check that table the next time the use logs in and restore the most recent season variable.

Comment: kindly can you write sample code of above logic, i think we are going to right direction

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: hmmm ,, nice dear. can you communicate with me on Skype? my skype id is "csit111",,, i m waiting for you,

Comment: No, I'm not available on Skype, I'm just trying to help out other programmers. If you edit your question and post the code that you're currently using I'm sure the community will be able to help you.